# Linker errors in GoogleMobileVision when using Firebase ML Kit on iOS without cocapods

Tags: xcode, firebase, linker-errors, firebase-mlkit, google-ios-vision

I am trying to add the MLVisionTextModel of Firebase 5.0.1 into an Xcode project without cocoapods. I have added all the dependent frameworks as stated in the Readme.md file. Getting the following linker errors:

> Showing All Messages
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LAContext", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeCache_f189776e75765630b82721fafea64052.o)
>     "_vImageConverter_CreateWithCGImageFormat", referenced from:
>         +[GMVUtility(Internal) sampleBuffer32BGRATo32RGBA:] in GoogleMobileVision(GMVUtility+Internal_1a3089c1f18dbb4046735909972b8cb2.o)
>     "_vImageConvert_AnyToAny", referenced from:
>         +[GMVUtility(Internal) sampleBuffer32BGRATo32RGBA:] in GoogleMobileVision(GMVUtility+Internal_1a3089c1f18dbb4046735909972b8cb2.o)
>     "_vImageConverter_Release", referenced from:
>         +[GMVUtility(Internal) sampleBuffer32BGRATo32RGBA:] in GoogleMobileVision(GMVUtility+Internal_1a3089c1f18dbb4046735909972b8cb2.o)
>     "_vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage", referenced from:
>         +[GMVUtility(Internal) rgbaPixelDataFromCGImage:] in GoogleMobileVision(GMVUtility+Internal_1a3089c1f18dbb4046735909972b8cb2.o)
>     "_vImageRotate_ARGB8888", referenced from:
>         +[GMVUtility(Internal) rotatePixelData:width:height:bytesPerRow:withAngle:] in GoogleMobileVision(GMVUtility+Internal_1a3089c1f18dbb4046735909972b8cb2.o)
>     "_vImageHorizontalReflect_ARGB8888", referenced from:
>         +[GMVUtility(Internal) flipRGBA8888Horizontally:width:height:bytesPerRow:] in GoogleMobileVision(GMVUtility+Internal_1a3089c1f18dbb4046735909972b8cb2.o)
>     "_vImagePermuteChannels_ARGB8888", referenced from:
>         +[GMVUtility(Internal) permutate:width:height:bytesPerRow:order:] in GoogleMobileVision(GMVUtility+Internal_1a3089c1f18dbb4046735909972b8cb2.o)
>     "_vImageFlatten_RGBA8888ToRGB888", referenced from:
>         +[GMVUtility(Internal) flattenRGBA8888ToRGB888:width:height:bytesPerRow:] in GoogleMobileVision(GMVUtility+Internal_1a3089c1f18dbb4046735909972b8cb2.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue got resolved after adding Accelerate.framework as part of the build phases in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase frameworks are built statically, so if you are adding them manually to your project they **should not** be under **embedded binaries** in xcode under your application target. If you have it there removing it should fix the issue.

Comment: Have added all of them under `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`. Don't have any entries under `Embedded Binaries`.

Comment: Did you add all off the frameworks necessary for GoogleMobileVision? They will be under the same folder if you downloaded from here https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks

Comment: Are they also added in the framework search path and header search paths? Can you share a github repo with your current project setting? Also I can see that you’re trying to compile for the simulator, do you get the same result if running on the phone? Finally the methods you’re trying to access belong to a GMVUtility category called internal, which makes me think those header are meant to be hidden. If you browse the framework in the filesystem

Comment: Can you find GMVUtility+Internal.h?

Comment: I have added all the required frameworks from Firebase for FirebaseMLVisionTextModel along with LocalAuthentication & StoreKit system frameworks. The Framework path is also added in both Framework & Header search paths. When I check the GoogleMobileVision.framework in the file system, I am able to only find GMVUtility.h and not GMVUtility+Internal.h

Comment: So it seems like GoogleMobileVision is missing one of its dependencies, please check from the link I sent you above that you have all the frameworks in the folder for vision. If possible remove what you have and add back from there. I have got this working last week so otherwise you can share a GitHub project and I’ll take a look.

Comment: I have added all the dependencies from the link that you have shared. I am using Firebase SDK v5.1.0. I have uploaded my Xcode project at the following WeTransfer link: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/18b56cfab3968065fe8d46379f50498320180524105033/1db7e4

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the GMVUtility+Internal.h file in case you have it?

Comment: I don't have it. Probably part of google private headers and that's why they aren't sharing it.  I downloaded the project you shared but it doesn't compile, missing 'rhodes' files. However I can see in the framework search path you have $(PROJECT_DIR)/Frameworks , can you set that to recursive and see if it fixes the issue?

Comment: Hey, thanks for all the help! The issue was resolved after adding Accelerate framework.